# WSo2 Esb filtering messages to an output file

Tags: filter, wso2, esb, mediator

I am working with a filter mediator attempting to send messages to an output xml file. I have my sequence using a filter mediator based on a attribute value, if it is true I want to write the message to a new xml file in a certain directory. If it is false I will drop the record. 
Here is my sequence:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="RenaissanceIqtFilterSequence">
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="sequence" value="FilterSequence"></property>
   </log>
   <filter xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:z="RowsetSchema" xpath="//z:row/@name='RP'">
      <then>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="sequence" value="Condition Write"></property>
         </log>
         <call-template target="FileWriteTemplate">
            <with-param name="targetFileName" value="NEW_MESSAGE_FILE"></with-param>
            <with-param name="addressUri" value="vfs:file:///var/process/rrout"></with-param>
         </call-template>
      </then>
      <else>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="sequence" value="Condition Drop"></property>
         </log>
         <drop></drop>
      </else>
   </filter>
</sequence>
```

*I am using a template as you can see to write out to my new output file setting parameters for the file name and uri.

The result is the whole file is being written out to the directory not just the messages I want. I have been running google searches trying to see where I am going wrong. I assume at this point I may be using the Filter mediator incorrectly? Maybe there is a better way or mediator to use to accomplish this task? I would appreciate any thoughts or recommendations folks may have. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I can see that you have different log messages for each condition. Do you see in your log the message "Condition Drop" somewhere ?

Comment: I do not, I am only seeing Condition Write in my logs.

Comment: After running some more tests, from what i am seeing the ESB is wrapping the whole xml files in SOAP tags at the beginning and end of the file so it appears to be treating the whole files as 1 message. I was trying to process all the rows in the xml file(inparticular the "z:row//") and filter off messages to a new file based on my xpath. I think I am not handling this scenario correctly. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Sorry,  I totally overlooked that part. You should use the iterate mediator in order to split elements in your file. Another approach is to use a xslt or smooks  transform in order to select only the required elements from the input file.

Comment: I have made some more progress. I have created a new question here on the latest issue i have hit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808655/wso2-esb-filtering-messages-to-an-output-file-part-2